# getting TCP headers from Ngnix Lua ssl_certificate_by_lua_file context

Tags: nginx, lua

using Ngnix is a bit new for me, I am trying to get the ssl related data such ssl_cipher and ttl (data which is connected to the tcp headers) from ssl_certificate_by_lua_file context using lua inside Ngnix

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not doable, I decided to create a sniffer on the machine for this kind of data.
Thanks